# difference between wget and apt get

Tags: linux, unix, wget, apt-get

Im trying to install google's tensor flow API and i'm following their instructions on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/v0.6.0/get_started/os_setup.html) link to no avail.
after typing the following command:

> sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev

i get:

> sudo: apt-get: command not found

I'm new to Linux and i was told there are tow types, red-hat and a nameless parallel, which answers respectively to either wget or apt-get. I was also told i need to adjust the commands. (wget does works)

is this true? What is the accurate difference between wget and apt-get? how do i adjust the commands to my situation?

i'm working with:

SUSE Linux Enterprise server 11 (x86_64)
release 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apt-get is a package manager for Debian distros while SUSE Linux is equipped with zypper.
You can use:

```
zypper install python-devel python-pip
```

You can also compile python without using package manager like zypper. Wget is used to download things and is not a package manager. Thus when you will compile, you'll need the package. So you'll use wget.

Comment: So the difference here is simply the distributor of the system? how do i adjust the rest of the instructions? simply replace each apt-get with zypper?

Comment: Not every time it'll work. As there are some package name differences. For Debian it was python-dev and here it is python-devel. I'll see the instructions and will tell you the modifications.

Comment: In the case of virtualenv you can use zypper install python-devel python-pippython-virtualenvwrapper . Rest seems fine.

Answer (score 4):

Suse Linux has not installed apt-get by default. you should go with zypper:

```
zypper install python-devel python-pip
```

apt-get is a packagemanagment system while wget is only good for filetransfer